# Compiling fortran and C++ program and linking from intel compiler

Tags: c++, fortran, intel-fortran

I have a Fortran main program under which there are many subroutines. One of the subroutine calls a c++ function. That c++ function is calling another Fortran subroutine. Now I need to compile all of them together to get the output.
I have tried to compile c++ file with icl. Then I have used ifort as a linker between Fortran file and object file created for the c++. But the method is not working. Its showing unresolved external symbol.

Comment: Provide a minimal example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, calling C from Fortran, or fortran from C to get more than just theoretical suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide more information like code example?

Comment: I need to know the compiling process only. Like if there are only fortran subroutines then: ifort /c *.f and after that ifort /exe:trial1 *.obj. So what command needs to be modified if there are subroutine in c++ also.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you at least saw this: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/691954

What they wrote there mostly refers to C,  though there is mention of C++ libraries. IF you link with C++ ocde, you need those.
You should read about symbol name mangling in C++.  Because C++ supports overloaded funktions but linker requires *unique* symbols, C++ generates 
something like `_foo****@8` instead of `foo` for a function foo(int i, float j), where * depend on compiler and on type of arguments.

Fortran code generates C-styled symbols if BIND(C) used, you can  force C++ to generate one for a function , by using `extern "C"` in C++ code both for prototypes of fortran functions called from C++ and for functions that will be called from fortran.

This example works with C compiler, but for C++ you need to change  symbol generated (https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/691929#92BDCE7A-30FA-4A60-BCDB-7CE1521572EC). Note that C and Fortran interoperability isn't standardized and usually not portable from one compiler set to another. I had to deal with problem that  Compaq compiler was mangling function names as well but not in C++ way, or that PGI Fortran required stdcall conventions.

***Fortran Code Example***

```
subroutine Simulation(alpha, beta, gamma, delta, arrays) BIND(C) 
   use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING 
   implicit none 
   integer (C_LONG), value :: alpha 
   real (C_DOUBLE), intent(inout) :: beta 
   integer (C_LONG), intent(out) :: gamma 
   real (C_DOUBLE),dimension(*),intent(in) :: delta
   type, BIND(C) :: pass 
      integer (C_INT) :: lenc, lenf
      type (C_PTR) :: c, f 
   end type pass 
   type (pass), intent(inout) :: arrays
   real (C_FLOAT), ALLOCATABLE, target, save :: eta(:)
   real (C_FLOAT), pointer :: c_array(:) 
   ... 
   ! Associate c_array with an array allocated in C 
   call C_F_POINTER (arrays%c, c_array, (/arrays%lenc/) ) 
   ... 
   ! Allocate an array and make it available in C 
   arrays%lenf = 100 
   ALLOCATE (eta(arrays%lenf)) 
   arrays%f = c_loc(eta) 
   ... 
end subroutine Simulation
```

***C Struct declaration Example***

```
struct pass {int lenc, lenf; float *c, *f;};
```

***C Function Prototype Example***

```
void simulation(long alpha, double *beta,
     long *gamma, double delta[], struct pass *arrays);
```

***C Calling sequence Example***

```
simulation(alpha, &beta, &gamma, delta, &arrays);
```